# What's the best fastener for a carpet that won't cause unraveling?

Tags: carpet, drywall-anchor, fastener

Last time I tried this, the drywall screws I was using snagged and started unraveling the carpet.

Is there a particular kind of screw that won't snag carpets? It's a loop/pile carpet so snagging is pretty likely.

Nails unfortunately aren't going to suffice unless they are maybe resistant to being pulled out like a screw would be.

And yeah... I'm putting it into drywall.

Comment: You're screwing a carpet onto your wall?

Comment: Yup. :) Well I screwed one in before and it went less than optimally... So I started this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use carpet staples, and if your carpet is heavy you want to use a lot of them.  If it is heavy and permanent then use glue also.

Comment: Glue huh. Good thinking. Any recommendation for a glue that will do carpet to drywall?

Comment: On second thought I do actually want to be able to remove the carpet down the road potentially and glue makes that tricky...

Comment: You might consider putting a layer, like 3/8" plywood, between the drywall and carpet that you can screw into the stud and will hold staples better than drywall.

Comment: Ended up using double sided carpet tape (didn't know that was a thing) and a bunch of staples. Working well. A plywood definitely would help secure it better if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two common ways to hang carpets for display:

1. By hand sew a loop of fabric along the top edge at the back of the carpet, insert a rod. Put 3-4 suitable hooks on the wall and hang.
2. By hand sew heavy duty velcro patches along each edge of the carpet. Attach the other half of the velcro to the wall with a suitable method (could be glued to a board that you then hang). Stick the carpet up.

1) is clearly easier to achieve, and tends to be used in homes. 2) is more common in museums where they like to move installations around, and want the hanging method to be invisible.